# Laravel eloquent updating tinyint (boolean)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a weird issue when updating eloquent model, I use a checkbox (1 || undefined ) and patch all the data after validation using

```
$input = $request->all();
$service->update($input);
```

I tried to check the checkbox specifically

```
$input['active'] = ($request->has('active') && $input['active']) ? 1 : 0
```

but it still wouldn't affect the database.

When I dump the `Request` I can see `active:` `1` or `0` but nothing of that changes the database on `update()`

I did a quick testing and using

```
$service->active = ($request->has('active') && $input['active']) ? 1 : 0 ;
$service->save();
```

did the job. But why the `update()` isn't updating this field ?

Comment: How about just `$input['active'] = $request->has('active') ? 1 : 0`

Comment: When you `dd($request->input('active'))` does it return `true`?

Comment: Also, do you get an error when you try this or does it work and just not update that field?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If `$request->active` returns true, but it still doesn't save in DB, I bet you forgot to add `active` to a `$fillable` array:

```
protected $fillable = ['something', 'something_else', 'active'];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: That was it .. I though I added them all.

Comment: Thanks ! Worked for me but can you explain why it is happen

Comment: @VinayKaithwas you can't easily interact with the columns which not present in the $fillable array.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
$input = $input->except(['active']);

$input['active'] = ($request->has('active') && $input['active']) ? 1 : 0;

$service->update($input);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works too , but it's prefered to use `true` and `false` (instead of 1 and 0) while dealing with booleans in Laravel